# how to get the indexpath of selected Action sheet picker Swift

Tags: json, swift

I have got myself into confusion.I need someone to help me.
I have been trying to use Action sheet picker and everything was good but I need to get the selected item. How can I do it?

```
 ActionSheetMultipleStringPicker.show(withTitle: "Select Country", rows: [
        countriesArray,], initialSelection: [0],
    doneBlock: {
            picker, indexes, values in


            print("values = \(values)")
            print("indexes = \(indexes)")
            print("picker = \(picker)")

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    // Update UI
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "pdfsegue", sender: nil)
                }
            return
    }, cancel:
        {
            ActionMultipleStringCancelBlock in return

    }, origin: sender)
```

these are my arrays:

```
var emiratesArray = [String]()
var emiratesIdArray = [Int]()
```

I am getting values into my arrays from JSON:

```
let url = NSURL(string: EMIRATES_URL)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as?URL)!, completionHandler: {(data,response,error) ->
        Void in

        if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary
        {

            print(jsonObj.value(forKey: "data")!)


            if let messageArray = jsonObj.value(forKey: "data") as? NSArray
            {
                for message in messageArray
                {
                    if let messageDict = message as? NSDictionary
                    {

                        if let data = data {


                            let successmessage = jsonObj.value(forKey: "success") as? Int

                            if(successmessage == 1)
                            {

                                if let emirate_name = messageDict.value(forKey: "emirate_name")
                                {
                                    self.emiratesArray.append(emirate_name as! String)
                                    print(emirate_name)

                                }

                                if let company_id = messageDict.value(forKey: "id")
                                {
                                    self.emiratesIdArray.append(company_id as! Int)
                                    print(company_id)
                                }


                            } else
                            {

                            }

                        }


                    }
                }
            }

        }


    }).resume()
```

someone help me How to get the selected item?If i were using tableview then I would have taken the id from the [indexpath.row] but in UIActionsheet picker,I dont know how get the id of selected value. Please someone help me please

Comment: You will get the selected item in `values` array

Comment: I need to get the Id of selected item in Values array. How can I get it?

Comment: What your `countriesArray` contains? `String` or any custom class object?

Comment: custom class objects

Comment: Please provide your custom class code

Comment: t@Torongo please see the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't found any Custom Class in your given code. You can create a class like below:

```
class Emirate: NSObject {
    var id: Int
    var name: String

    init(id: Int, name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }

    override var description: String {
        return self.name
    }
}
```

I have override the `description` property because  `ActionSheetMultipleStringPicker` shows description of object given in the array if it is not `String`.

Declare your `Emirate` array

```
var emiratesArray = [Emirate]()
```

Your API request and Parsing should be like this:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "EMIRATES_URL")
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as?URL)!, completionHandler: {(data,response,error) ->
    Void in

    if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary
    {

        print(jsonObj.value(forKey: "data")!)


        if let messageArray = jsonObj.value(forKey: "data") as? NSArray
        {
            for message in messageArray
            {
                if let messageDict = message as? NSDictionary
                {

                    if let data = data {


                        let successmessage = jsonObj.value(forKey: "success") as? Int

                        if(successmessage == 1)
                        {

                            if let emirate_name = messageDict.value(forKey: "emirate_name") as? String, let company_id = messageDict.value(forKey: "id") as? Int
                            {
                                self.emiratesArray.append(Emirate(id: company_id, name: emirate_name))
                                print(emirate_name)
                            }


                        } else
                        {

                        }

                    }


                }
            }
        }

    }


}).resume()
```

Now feed your action sheet `self.emiratesArray`

```
ActionSheetMultipleStringPicker.show(withTitle: "Select Country", rows: [
    self.emiratesArray], initialSelection: [0],
                      doneBlock: {
                        picker, indexes, values in


                        print("values = \(values)")
                        print("indexes = \(indexes)")
                        print("picker = \(picker)")

                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            // Update UI
                            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "pdfsegue", sender: nil)
                        }
                        return
}, cancel:
    {
        ActionMultipleStringCancelBlock in return

}, origin: sender)
```

You will now get the selected `Emirate` class objects in `values` array.

N.B- This code is just to give you an idea about how it can work.